# How can I change an image/bitmap that is already in use?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have a directory with .png images which I display in a third party combobox of my c# program. So the user is able to choose one of this images using the combo box. Basic code used:

```
Bitmap thump = new Bitmap(<path>);
ComboItem item = new ComboItem();
item.Image = thump;
MyComboBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Now I would like to update one of this images at runtime. Unfortunately I can't delete the old image because it is still opened in my program, so somehow I either need to close it or open it in a way that does not keep the image in use by my program. The changes to the bitmap are not done in my program, I just pass the path of the dirctory to another program which saves the bitmap there (but fails at the moment because it can't delete the old bitmap).

I guess this is a simple problem but I could not find a solution here or on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the file to memory, then create the Bitmap using that data.

```
var m = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
Bitmap thump = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(m);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I had to do: Bitmap thump = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(m); but otherwise it does what I need!